# In the Warehouse 13 series finale ending scene, where are they?

Tags: ending, warehouse-13

The final episode begins with

> Warehouse 13 rumbling as it’s about to transition/move to a nebulous Warehouse 14. However, by the final scene the next generation of Warehouse Agents still appear to be in Warehouse 13 but many decades into the future.

Did I miss something?